# how to use date picker on dynamically generated objects

Tags: javascript

I want to use datepicker, while I am generating text boxes on which i need to use date picker.
can any one tell me how i can use.

Answer (score 1):

After creating your text box dynamically use jquery to make it in to a date picker.

```
$('#divId').append('<input type="textbox" id="txtId"/>');//create text box

$('#txtId').datepicker();//create date picker
```